# The conversion of a datetime2 to a datetime is out of range

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

Have read a number of posts about this issue but haven't found anything that works.

Our SQL database has the field set up like so (Data Type of `datetime`)

[image]

The respective model property has the following declarations

```
    [DisplayName("Effective Date")]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```

Yet if I enter a date of `11/11/1111` I get the following error when my program runs `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated

I am not aware of, nor have found, any range specifications in our ASP MVC project or on the SQL table. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have specified column type as:

```
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]
```

This will map to [`Dateime` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187819.aspx) column in SQL server, **[and not `Datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.100).aspx)**.

`DateTime` has a valid range of January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999 so your value `11/11/1111` is out of range.

The error message includes `datetime2` and that is due the the provided value `11/11/1111`, which would fall under `datetime2` range.

Comment: Is there anything other than a manual validation routine that would work for this?

Comment: @NealR, if you have the need to store values outside of the range mentioned, and have the option of changing the column's data type, you could make it a `DateTime2`.

Comment: Thanks. It was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` data type's range for MSSQL is `January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

The error message stating the use of `datetime2` is a bit misleading, but ultimately the issue is that you're trying to use a date that is out of the range of the `DateTime` data type.